# SQL Instance not reachable

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, instance

Please excuse my bad English.

I've got the following problem: I have a Domain Controller (`DC1`) with different running SQL Server instances, f.e.: `MSSQLSERVER`, `SQLEXPRESS`, `PROMAN`.

I've got 4 workstations: on 3 of them every instance is reachable. On the 4. Workstation are all the instances reachable, except the instance `MSSQLSERVER`. I've tried everything: complete turn off of the firewall, named pipes, tcp-ports ..... I even removed on this workstation all SQL services/installs and re-install it. It didn't work out.

Another workstation can reach the instance `MSSQLSERVER`, but if I run SQL Server Management Studio, I can't see the instance `MSSQLSERVER`.

Something is wrong and I don't know where to look to solve the problem without reinstalling the 4. workstation.

Has anyone a logical explanation for this?

Thank you very much!

PS: The DC runs Windows Server 2012 / SQL Server 2012 Express. The workstations are using Windows 10.

Comment: Hey, what about the port 1433 in firewall, Is it accessible from outside?

Comment: in SSMS login to servername\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: The `MSSQLSERVER` instance is the **default** instance which you can connect to with just the `machinename` as your server name (*without* specifying an instance name)

Comment: @chris  are you running sqlexpress or sql standard/enterprise?